# How to prevent click event on Header of JQUERY DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https:cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.3/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

 
 
 $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
                $('#my_modal').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
                var UserID = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
                //$(".modal-body #txtUserIDEdit").val(UserID);
                $("[id$='txtUserIDEdit']").val(UserID);
                var UserName = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                //$(".modal-body #txtUserNameEdit").val(UserName);
                $("[id$='txtUserNameEdit']").val(UserName);
                GetSaveRecord();
                GetUserPassword();
            });
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
<thead>
<tr><th>S.No</th>
<th>User Login</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Plant</th>
<th>Status</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
  {

    [
      "1",
      "Armand",
      "Warren",
      "56045",
      "Taiwan, Province of China"
    ],
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

 <div class="modal" id="my_modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" style="width: 600px;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <b style="font-size: 25px; text-align: center;">FAV-VS Edit Details</b>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table border="0" class="width100p">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%--<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">   class="contentTable"  id="trdisplaytable"--%>
                                    <%-- <table id="tblEdit">--%>
                                    <%-- <tr>--%>
                                    <%-- <td>--%>   <%-- class="ui-corner-all contentTable"--%>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>User ID</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserIDEdit" ForeColor="#808080" CssClass="width50p input-tb" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" MaxLength="150"
                                                    Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>User Name</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserNameEdit" ForeColor="#808080" CssClass="width50p input-tb" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" MaxLength="150"
                                                    Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Password</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" CssClass="width50p input-tb" runat="server" MaxLength="10" TextMode="Password"
                                                    Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>Confirm Password</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" CssClass="width50p input-tb" runat="server" MaxLength="10" TextMode="Password"
                                                    Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;<b>Status</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <%--<td>
                                            <input type="radio" name="Status" value="Active" /><b>Active</b>
                                            <input type="radio" name="Status" value="Inactive" /><b>Inactive</b>
                                        </td>--%>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Inactive" Value="Inactive"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;<b>Plant</b><span class="requierdField"><b>*</b>&nbsp;</span></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div id="checkboxplant" style="width: 100%; border: groove; height: 110px; overflow: auto">
                                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkPlantsAddNew" class="MyClass" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using jquery datatable as i am using sorting functionality of jquery datatable and also I am using click event of each row

`{I am just opening modal popup on click of Row}`

But it was happaning on click of header too. that i want to prevent, is there any wat to achieve same.

**click event of Row**

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
                $('#my_modal').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
                var UserID = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
                //$(".modal-body #txtUserIDEdit").val(UserID);
                $("[id$='txtUserIDEdit']").val(UserID);
                var UserName = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                //$(".modal-body #txtUserNameEdit").val(UserName);
                $("[id$='txtUserNameEdit']").val(UserName);
                GetSaveRecord();
                GetUserPassword();
            });
```

**To Prevent Header Information**

```
$('#example thead th').click(function () {
                var $select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>').on('click', function (e)
                { console.log(" click on select in column =" + $column.data()); e.stopPropagation(); });
            });
```

But no success. Can you please help me on same.

Comment: can you create a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind it to the `tbody` instead of the `table`.

```js
$('table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```css
thead tr
{
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Click me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: David this way it will work  but if i use `table` it will hit for all table ryt ? But i am looking for `datatable` only